Need a special function
I am looking for an algebraic expression for a possible function  with the following properties

$z=f(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ maps $\mathbb{R}^4$ to $\mathbb{R}$.
$f<1$ over $\mathbb{R}^4$.
All four first order partial derivatives are continuous and negative everywhere.
The limit to infinity for paths along the negative coordinate axes is $1$.

Any ideas?
The simpler the better.

How about
$$ f(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4) = 1 - \exp(x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4) $$
